Rich pwa install ui not available on desktop please add one screenshot with form_factor
Rich pwa install ui not available on desktop please add one screenshot with form_factor of wide and narrow is there any solution for this without using screenshots array?
I need solution where i don't have to use screenshot array in mt manifest file
"screenshots": [
{
"src": "data:image/png;base64,",
"sizes": "384x384",
"type": "image/png",
"form_factor": "wide",
"label": "No Screenshot"
},
{
  "src": "assets/icons/icon-384.png",
   "sizes": "384x384",
   "type": "image/png",
   "form_factor": "narrow",
   "label": "Application"
 }

]
I don't want to use this array in my file so that the diloag box of these screenshots will be not open in my web
